# Line size in ggplot2 3.4.0 and rayshader

Tags: r, ggplot2, rayshader

Just updated ggplot2 from 3.3.6 to 3.4.0. It has been documented that new version of ggplot2 replaced `size` with `linewidth` in `geom_line()` and `geom_sf()`.

However, it appears that the new version does not get along well with `rayshader` package on my machine with Ubuntu 22.04.

## ggplot2 3.3.6

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rayshader)
# df with geometry is not included
p <- df %>% ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry, fill = value), color = "black", size = 0.25) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "C", limits = c(0, 100)) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(100, 180), ylim = c(-60, -10)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
p
filename_movie <- tempfile()
plot_gg(p,
  zoom = 0.6,
  multicore = TRUE,
  raytrace = TRUE,
  phi = 30,
  theta = 0
)
render_snapshot(filename = "gr_1")
rgl::rgl.close()
```

[image]

The above is the expected graph.

## ggplot2 3.4.0

I used the same code, only difference is that `size = 0.25` was replaced by `linewidth = 0.25`. I got the following graph (obviously not correct). My current fix is to switch back to ggplot 3.3.6. It would be nice to use new ggplot2.

[image]

Comment: Well, while `ggplot2 3.4.0` introduced the `linewidth` argument, `size` could still be used as otherwise all old code will break. Only drawback is that you get a warning.

Comment: True, either `linewidth` or `size` worked fine when generating 2D graph `p` but when transforming 2D into 3D using `rayshader`, it produced an incorrect 3D graph, as shown in OP.

Comment: I had a look at the [changelog](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#breaking-changes-3-4-0) and it looks that `geom_sf` is a bit special: "For geoms that have both point sizing and linewidth sizing (geom_pointrange() and **geom_sf**) size now only refers to sizing of points which can leads to a visual change in old code".